# Celery, Django.. making a Task / thread launch sub-task / threads?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, celery

I'm using celery with django and am trying to get a Task, like the one below:

```
class task1 (Task)
   def run (self):
      launch_some_other_task.delay()
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, I can go into more detail as far as my code but figured I would just ask first if this sort of thing will work as doesn't seem to be working for me. I am finding this necessary as I am using selenium, a web testing framework, where sometimes it will just hang where I can't get any output from this so I want to be able to kill if off if a certain condition isn't met (updating a memcache variable with a certain value within a specified number of seconds).

Thanks for any advice on this

Comment: The code above should work (in theory)... What happens exactly?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, I think it just doesn't start the process its supposed to.. my code is kind of messy and complicated (since its built around the selenium software which is kind of unpredictable at times, at least for what I'm using it for). I am going to make a more simple test so I can post that up here tomorrow (the code)

Comment: For me, it sounds like You are hacking Selenium for what it is not supposed to do: how is production code related to testing Selenium code? How is Selenium unpredictable if You're waiting for DOM properly? More code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've added the following to your `urls.py`:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```